# How can I put a parameter into a localized string in Android?

Tags: android, string, localization, android-resources

I need to put a dynamic piece of text into a localized string but it has to go into different locations depending on the language.

For example, I need two strings like:

English:  The current time is HH:mm:ss
Another Language: HH:mm:ss is the current time

I can think of one approach, which is to have a preDate and postDate localized string where postDate is empty in English and preDate is empty in Other.  This will work but doesn't seem very elegant or scalable.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I use this in my string resource.

```
<string name="duration"><xliff:g id="minutes" example="42" >%s</xliff:g> mins <xliff:g id="seconds" example="28" >%s</xliff:g> secs</string>
```

Which prints xx mins yy secs when you call:

```
getString(R.string.duration, minutes, seconds);
```

In another language, you can translate it by changing the location of mins and secs.
It should print, for example: mins xx secs yy

A schema should be include at header:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="rn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

Comment: Looks promising, but when I paste that into my strings.xml, I get this error:  `error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

Comment: You might want to include the xmlns:xliff at header.

Comment: That did the trick.  I already accepted the other answer but I have given you an upvote too.

Comment: @Calvin How can use drawable here..any idea?

Comment: @Calvin what are the option are available for reading value like here using %s and %d...i want to map drawable image here...please let me know if any one have idea about it?

Comment: Is the `id` attribute here unique for the resources file, or just within a `string` tag?

Comment: is it possible to pass the arguments by name rather than positionally? i.e. `getString(R.string.duration, minutes=m, seconds=s)` ?

Answer (score 30):

Correct android xml strings format is `<string name="tst">string %1$s integer %2$d</string>`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you so much for String and Integer difference

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the right way.

Other not so good soln is if you put the whole format string in resources like

English: The current time is %d:%d:%d Another Language: %d:%d:%d is the current time

I generally dont like this approach as now your formatting code is split across two places.